# Can't run CD command inside a batchfile inside vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line, path, behavior, cd

When I tried to run a batchfile (with a cd command) outside vscode, it is working, but if inside vscode its not. What options do I have in order to run a CD command inside a batchfile inside vscode, when I try to open my project in vscode, it has a lengthy path, so I need to automatically cd to the correct path automatically by using a batchfile? Why does vscode behave like this?

Comment: please add minimal code that demonstrates the undesired behavior

Comment: I just have a batch file that has the cd command in it, when I run that batch file outside of vs code it correctly cd's to the target folder, whereas inside vscode (terminal), it doesn't work, the folder in which you started with the terminal, after running the batch file is still in that path

Comment: `after running the batch file is still in that path` ... what about inside the batch file? ... I would expect the batch file to leave the current environment unchanged ... are you using relative paths?

Comment: I used these lines, cd \, then cd /d c:\path\another\again, but with the actual path to what I would run, but it doesn't work...